# Android studio logcat nothing to show add keyworkd width Filters

Tags: android, filter

[image]

I am using Android Studio 3.0 
Build #AI-171.4408382, built on October 21, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1

public class LogTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_test);
    Log.d("","AAAAAA-------");
    Log.d("","AAAAAA-BBBBBBB");
```

//        Log.d("AAAAA-------","AAAAAA-------");  //doesn't show log

//        Log.d("AAAAAA-BBBBBBB","AAAAAA-BBBBBBB");//doesn't show log

```
}
```

}

I try to use the Logcat to see logs. but some time logcat doesn't work .
sometimes filter wokr but usually does not work, so I use No Filters, 
Can I use "Show only selected application" filter?
I think Android Studio Setting is wrong.

pleas help me Thanks

Comment: Use how only selected application or you can create own app logcat by set the package in Edit Filter configuration. also remove AAAAAA from search. this will only see if your logcat data match with given string in search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove AAAAAA from your search text. Its beside Regex selection box

Log.d(tag,value);

You are setting the key as "" but filtering with AAAAAA key. Try changing it to the following.

```
 Log.d("AAAAAA-------","my logs");
 Log.d("AAAAAA-BBBBBBB","my logs");
```

Comment: I want to  include "AAAAAA" strings

Comment: There wont be any log printed if AAAAAA is empty. You should try something like Log.d("AAAAAA",somevalue == null ?"null":somevalue );

Comment: Should be get log my code is So simple OnCreate do log

Comment: Your problem is that it should be Log.d("AAAAAA",""); not Log.d("","AAAAA");

Comment: I think don'ts matter Log.d(String tag, String msg) -tag, or msg.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

My AndroidStudio setting is somethins wrong.

Comment: Why dont you try it? =)

Answer (score 1):

Change     `Log.d("","AAAAAA-------");` to `Log.d("AAAAAA-------", "");`

You will be able to see in logs

Also do the same for  Log.d("","AAAAAA-BBBBBBB"); as well.

So finally you should do

```
Log.d("AAAAAA-------", "");
Log.d("AAAAAA-BBBBBBB", "");
```

Check out official information about [Log.d()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.

Here is explanation:

> Log.d(String tag, String msg)
>
> `tag` String: Used to identify the source of a log message. It usually
>   identifies the class or activity where the log call occurs.
>
> `msg` String: The message you would like logged.